# Apply a variable rate of change using the previous value in R

Tags: r

I am trying to do something I believe easy in Excel, but in R. The concept is roughly compound interest with a variable interest rate that can either increase or decrease and uses last year's value. I want the value of x to be determined by the previous value of x added to the previous value of x multiple by the rate in another vector. This should occur recursively throughout the vector.

The math is: x[i+1] = x[i] + x[i]*rate[i]

I have tried exploring this with `stats::filter` and using `lag` in `dplyr`, but either they can't handle the variable rate, or the output vector seems to drift slightly from the value it should be.

Here is some simulated data:

```
set.seed(2)
x <- 100 ## initial data
rate <- rnorm(5,1)/100 ## generate random rate of change
```

So that rate is:

```
rate = c(0.001030855, 0.011848492, 0.025878453, -0.001303757, 0.009197482)
```

The output I want is:

```
x.with.rate <- c(100.1031, 101.2892, 103.9104, 103.7749, 104.7294)
```

Preferably no loop please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic can be reduced to `(X_0)*((1+R_0)*(1+R_1)...(1+R_n))`

i.e.

```
set.seed(2)
x <- 100 ## initial data
rate <- rnorm(5,1)/100 ## generate random rate of change
(x)*cumprod((1+rate))

[1] 100.1031 101.2892 103.9104 103.7749 104.7294
```

Comment: amazing thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for too long

Answer (score 0):

Use `Reduce`

```
Reduce(function(x, r) x * (1 + r), init = 100, rate, acc = TRUE)[-1]
## [1] 100.1031 101.2892 103.9104 103.7749 104.7294
```