# Group by with multi rate compound interest in R

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by

I have a data table with some simple stock data:

```
library(dplyr)

ticker    price   date          pct chge
AAPL      123.45  2020-02-04     0
AAPL      124.21  2020-02-05     0.615
AAPL      126.73  2020-02-06     2.029
AAPL      125.68  2020-02-07    -0.829
AAPL      125.51  2020-02-08    -0.135
AMZN      237.32  2020-02-04     0
AMZN      242.67  2020-02-05     2.254
AMZN      243.44  2020-02-06     0.317
AMZN      243.38  2020-02-07    -0.025
AMZN      247.93  2020-02-08     1.870
```

Trying to group by stock and then compound the interest cumulatively, i.e. start with $100, then multiply it each by price change percentage difference, looping through to reach a continuous compound as opposed to a normal compound result which is levied at the end.

Efforts include:

```
df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  summarise(Pct_growth = sum(df$pct))
```

This just gives the same figure in each row against the stock tickers.

Looking through [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53340949/apply-a-variable-rate-of-change-using-the-previous-value-in-r), I've come across `cumprod` but it ends up like this:

```
x <- 100
df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  Pct_growth = (x)*cumprod((1+df$pct))
```

and then I get:

```
Error in df_new <- df %>% group_by(ticker) %>% df_new$Pct_growth = (x) *  : 
could not find function "<-<-"
```

Trawled SO for some time and not finding a clear answer but would be grateful for any help.

To do this in Excel, I would enter a nominal figure of 100 in cell E2 and then, in E3:

```
=IF(A3<>A2, 100, E2*(1+(D2/100))
```

which I would then click and drag down.

This would complete the column but what I was looking for was the final figure from that calc for each stock:

```
AAPL    101.668019
AMZN    104.470232
```

Comment: You cannot code like this in a dplyr chain. This is simply not valid. You need to summarise or mutate Pct_growth.

Comment: What is the formula you want to implement here? Can you let me know?

Comment: I want to create a new dataframe with: 'ticker' column with 'AAPL' and 'AMZN' in it, matched with iterative compound interest in column 2. E.g. for AAPL, 1 x 1.00615 x 1.02029 x 0.99171 x 0.99865. Hope that explains it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not clear about the formula that you want to implement but the key is to not use `$` in `dplyr` chain. Using `df$pct` will return the `pct` value from the complete dataframe and not from a particular group.

```
library(dplyr)

x <- 100

df_new <- df %>%
  group_by(ticker) %>%
  mutate(Pct_growth = x * cumprod(1 + pct)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

The same goes for `sum` as well -

```
df_new <- df %>% group_by(ticker) %>% summarise(Pct_growth = sum(pct))
```

Comment: The first snippet works on the small dataset I've created but when I run against a larger set, it seems to miss out the first ticker symbol. The second snippet has the same result, for some reason, albeit the return for the simpler set is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Foothill_trudger That's strange it should not drop any ticker ideally. Can you check the values of the ticker that is being dropped? What are they? Is it possible to provide a reproducible example to check this?

Comment: That seems to work now, I shall go through and do a mega cross test with Excel but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `aggregate` in `base R`

```
aggregate(pct ~ ticker, df, FUN = sum)
```